# Not able to get Apple Pay payment session

Tags: node.js, applepay, applepayjs

We are trying to implement ApplePay on the web in my project.  As per apple documentation i am getting the validation url from applejs api onvalidatemerchant function and i am passing this validation url to a node js route to get the apple payment session. This is the documentation i am following to get the apple payment session(https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple_pay_on_the_web/apple_pay_js_api/requesting_an_apple_pay_payment_session).

The below is the custom node js code i have written to get the apple payment session. The validation url ie)req.query.url passed to this node js route code is https://apple-pay-gateway-cert.apple.com/paymentservices/startSession.

```
app.get('/getAppleSession2', function (req, res) {


  var endpointURL = req.query.url;
  var cert_path = './apple_pay.pem';
  var cert = fs.readFileSync(cert_path);
  console.log('endpointURL is ' + endpointURL);
  console.log('cert_path is ' + cert_path);
  console.log('cert is'+cert);
  const options = {
    url: endpointURL,
    method: 'post',
    cert: cert,
    key: cert,
    body: {
      merchantIdentifier: "xxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxx",
      displayName: "xxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxx",
      initiative: "web",
      initiativeContext: "xxxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.com"
    },
    json: true,
  };
  //console.log("body" + body);
  request(options, function (error, response, body) {
    console.log('body of  getAppleSession' + body);
    console.log('Response from getAppleSession' + response);
    console.error('Error object ' + error);

    res.send(body);
  });

});
```

But this is the response i am getting for this route

```
body of  getAppleSession undefined
Response from getAppleSession undefined
Error object Error: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line
```

Not sure what is wrong here as i am doing this as per apple's documentation. I suspect if it has anything to do with how i am passing the certs(Merchant Identity certificate)to this nodejs route. I generated the certificate by downloading the Merchant Identity certificate in .cer format from Apple Development portal and converted the certificate i downloaded from Apple portal to .pem format by importing the .cer file in KeyChain access in my mac and exporting it to .pem in keychain access. I then placed the .pem file('./apple_pay.pem') in same directory of my node js route. Is there anything wrong in how i am generating the certificates or passing them in my node js route?

Not sure what is wrong here. Any code sample or pointers will be really helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like this is due to certificate validity related issue. Would you please ensure whether a self-signed certificate is valid.

Hope this may helps.

Answer (score 1):

I might be late, but leaving a working solution here for anyone else who stumbles upon this same issue:

Before beginning with the creation of api for requesting the `Apple Pay Session`, you need to the create the `payment processing` and `merchant identifier certificates`. A detailed explanation can be found at this [link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple_pay_on_the_web/configuring_your_environment):

At the end of the merchant identifier certificate process, you will be left with a `.cer` file. `Double click` on this file to add it to your `keychain` app.

After this, Go to your `keychain`, right click on certificate, and export it as PKCS #12 (.p12). You can then use openssl to convert this to a .pem file or you can use the .p12 directly (in nodejs with request. You need to set `agentOptions` as {pfx: p12File, and passphrase: '***'}.

My working solution for NodeJS is as below:

```js
async validateMerchant(ctx) {
  let response = {};
  try {
    const options = {
      url: ctx.query.validationURL,
      agentOptions: {
        pfx: fs.readFileSync(
          path.resolve(__dirname, 'MerchantIDCertificate.p12')
        ),
        passphrase: '********',
      },
      method: 'post',
      body: {
        merchantIdentifier: 'merchant.***.***.*****',
        displayName: 'Your Store Name',
        initiative: 'web',
        initiativeContext: 'Verified.domain.com',
      },
      json: true,
    };
    response = await this.promisifyRequest(options);
  } catch (error) {
    logger.error(error);
  }
  return response;
}

promisifyRequest(options) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request(options, (error, response, body) => {
      if (body) {
        console.log(response);
        return resolve(body);
      }
      if (error) {
        return reject(error);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: What is passphrase?

Comment: It's the password you used to create the .p12 file while exporting from Keychain.

Comment: @SalvinoD'sa Does this code still work for you ? I tried the same thing but I am getting "Error: unsupported"

Comment: I get "unsupported" as well. Could you update the solution?

Comment: We used above mentioned code as it's also we generated the .p12 from keychain. We have also cross-verified the .cer file which has the private key. But still we are getting an same error if we make call from both front-end | back-end.

Error Error: read ECONNRESET
    at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:220:20) {
  errno: -4077,
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  syscall: 'read'
}

Answer (score 0):

Look [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1DY6aD__cec&t=426s), how they use apple pay certificate:

[image]

Plus their docs are great, look [here](https://www.checkout.com/docs/payments/payment-methods/apple-pay/set-up-apple-pay)

Looks like we can also generate .pem file *without* .p12 file (according to their [docs](https://Looks%20like%20we%20can%20also%20generate%20.pem%20file%20without%20.p12%20file,%20which%20was%20an%20issue%20for%20me.)), which was an issue for me (because macOS disabled this format export in KeyChain Access, don't know why).

Another good tutorial:
https://ionutghisoi.medium.com/apple-pay-example-payments-2-86ff893fdc9c
and their example of code how to get payment session:

```
app.post('/validateSession', async (req, res) => {
    const { appleUrl } = req.body;

    // use set the certificates for the POST request
    httpsAgent = new https.Agent({
        rejectUnauthorized: false,
        cert: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, './certificate.pem')),
        key: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, './sandbox.key')),
    });

    response = await axios.post(
        appleUrl,
        {
            merchantIdentifier: 'your.apple.merchant.id',
            domainName: 'yourdomain.com',
            displayName: 'Your Shop Name',
        },
        {
            httpsAgent,
        }
    );
    res.send(response.data);
});
```